# custom error message for validates_length_of :maximum and :minimum on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write a custom  error message for :minimum and other for :maximum

I have the following the code line

```
validates_length_of :user_name, :minimum=>5,:maximum=>30

  ej if the length of :user_name is < 5 "The user_name must to have 5 characters as minimum"
  ej if the length of :user_name is > 30 "The user_name must to have 30 characters as maximum"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The newer notation for this is:

```
validates :user_name,
  length: { 
    minimum: 5,
    maximum: 30,
    too_short: "The user name must have at least %{count} characters.",
    too_long: "The user name must have no more than %{count} characters."
  }
```

More examples are listed in [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

The old `validates_length_of` type methods are left in there for legacy support but should probably be avoided in new code.

Answer (score 3):

maybe like
`validates_length_of :user_name, :minimum =>5,:maximum=>30, :too_short => 'is too short', :too_long => 'is too long'`

Comment: but how to remove the name of the model field in messege. I wrote this code:

  validates_length_of :subject, :maximum => 255, :too_long => 'checklist item is too long'


but my actual message  now is:  "Subject checklist item is too long"